# Sort descending all columns of data.frame

Tags: r

I'm fiddling with this now for a while, but can't find reasonable solution.

I would like to sort in descending order all columns of data.frame.

Sample data for instance:

```
CustomData <- data.frame(Value1=rnorm(100,1,2), Value2=rnorm(100,2,3),
                         Value3=rexp(100,5), Value4=rexp(100,2))
```

Works for one column:

```
CustomData[order(CustomData$Value1, decreasing=FALSE), ]
```

How sort all the columns data in decreasing/increasing order in reasonable manner? Thx.

I have also tried something like this as posted elsewhere, but doesn't work as stated.

```
CustomData[do.call(order, as.list(CustomData)),]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a dataframe by column(s) in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r)

Comment: Please note that `CustomData[do.call(order, as.list(CustomData)),]` sorts the whole dataframe *using columns other than the first one only to break ties*, which is a different problem than what you state - you want to sort the columns *independently*.

Comment: It seems like one of R's map or apply routines would help for mapping sort over the columns.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
CD.sorted <- apply(CustomData, 2, sort, decreasing=F)
#2 == column, 1 == row
```

Comment: 2 == column, 1 == row

Comment: I suggest to read a "R cookbook" - it contains a lot of real-world examples, that was very helpful for me in the begging.

Comment: Yes, I'm reading/learning, but when time is pressing, I don't have the luxury to spend hours on tasks like this. Thx.

Comment: I am not judging, that's just a really good book, example-based.

Comment: Found it now in pdf. Looks great. Thanks

Comment: To keep the dataframe structure, you can use this: `data.frame(lapply(CustomData,sort,decreasing=F))`

Comment: @chupvl: The R book is very basic indeed. It is for someone who is starting with statistics+programming from scratch.

Answer (score 8):

Using do.call is much faster.

For ascending order.

```
CustomData[do.call(order, CustomData),]
```

For decreasing order the syntax is a bit more elaborate because we have to pass the 'decreasing' argument.

```
CustomData[do.call(order, c(CustomData, list(decreasing=TRUE))),]
```

Comment: Even returns a `data.frame` straight away :)